# Images are not sharp in selected TabItem

Tags: wpf, icons, tabcontrol, tabitem, ico

I have a TabControl. The header of each TabItem contains a StackPanel with an icon and a Label.

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="/LoginPanel;component/Icons/icoLogin.ico"</Image>
        <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Login</Label>
        </StackPanel>
      </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <!--some further code here-->
  <TabItem>
  <!--some further code here-->
<TabControl>
```

Each icon in each non-selected TabItem is displayed as expected. The Icon in the currently selected TabItem is somewhat cloudy. If I switch to another Tab, the de-selected Tab-Icon becomes clear; the new selected Icon becomes cloudy.

I already tried the following to solve this:

```
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

but nothing happens

or

```
Width="32" Height="32"
```

or

```
Stretch="None"
```

to prevent scaling.
All of this without any effect. Can some please give me a hint? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<Image Source="/LoginPanel;component/Icons/icoLogin.ico"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"</Image>
```

Answer (score 10):

Consider setting 'RenderOptions.EdgeMode' to 'Aliased' too.

```
<Image Source="/LoginPanel;component/Icons/icoLogin.ico"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
```

See [Image in WPF getting blury](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645274/image-in-wpf-getting-blurry/5648419#5648419) here on SO.