# how can I resolve lose quality of png files in wpf

Tags: wpf

I use a PNG file on wpf windows with image control and use a PNG file on windowsform with picturebox control !
but the png file on windows form have more quality than wpf !
how can I resolve it in wpf !
the same as picture!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image in WPF getting Blurry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645274/image-in-wpf-getting-blurry)

Answer (score 1):

On the WPF side, try adding this attribute to the Image node

```
<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
```